# How to implement fallback page with Ionic 4 router (and without Angular)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, stenciljs

I am using Ionic 4 and Stenciljs for a progressive web app (PWA) and I am not also using Angular. I am using ion-router for the routing. Can anybody help me understand how to implement a fallback "Page Not Found" page to display when someone enters a URL for which there is no defined route (i.e. a page that does not exist)? All the examples I can find assume the use of Angular, but I'm trying to see if I get where I need with just standard web components and no additional framework.

Following is how some of my current router code looks (it makes use of the tabs component).

```
return (
  <ion-router useHash={false}>
    <ion-route-redirect from="/" to='/blog' />
    <ion-route component="page-tabs">
      <ion-route url="/blog" component="tab-blog">
        <ion-route component="page-blog"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>

      <ion-route url="/books" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-books"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/art" component="tab-art">
        <ion-route component="page-art"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/about" component="tab-about">
        <ion-route component="page-about"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/beaver-cage-command-chron" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-cmd-chron-beaver-cage"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/cage" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-cage"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/d-1-3-weapons-platoon" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-photos-weapons-platoon"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/ray-kelley-silver-star" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-ray-kelley-silver-star"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/photos" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route url="/:name" component="app-photos"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>
      <ion-route url="/vietnam-1967-amphibious-combat" component="tab-books">
        <ion-route component="page-vietnam-1967-amphibious-combat"></ion-route>
      </ion-route>

      {blogPostRoutes}

    </ion-route>

  </ion-router>
);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of that this is possible is using [multiple route redirects](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/route-redirect#multiple-route-redirects):

```html
<ion-router>
  <ion-route url="/one" component="page-one" />
  <ion-route url="/two" component="page-two" />
  <ion-route url="/three" component="page-three" />
  <ion-route url="/404" component="page-404" />

  <ion-route-redirect from="/one" to="/one" />
  <ion-route-redirect from="/two" to="/two" />
  <ion-route-redirect from="/three" to="/three" />
  <ion-route-redirect from="*" to="/404" />
</ion-router>
```

That is because only the first matching route-redirect will be called. However this becomes quite unfeasible for a large number of routes. A feature request for adding a fallback route is being tracked on [Ionic's Github Repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18687).

---

**Edit:** I actually just had the idea of wrapping this in a functional component to avoid having so much duplication:

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from '@stencil/core';
import { JSX } from '@ionic/core';

export const Route: FunctionalComponent<JSX.IonRoute> = props => [
  <ion-route {...props} />,
  <ion-route-redirect from={props.url} to={props.url} />,
];
```

```html
import { Route } from './route';

<ion-router>
  <Route url="/one" component="page-one" />
  <Route url="/two" component="page-two" />
  <Route url="/three" component="page-three" />

  <ion-route-redirect from="*" to="/404" />
</ion-router>
```

Comment: That's interesting, and thanks for sharing your work-around. I was able to implement my own work-around by checking the entered URL path against my known URL list and then dynamically adding the route for the unknown URL to Page Not Found when the entered URL does not exist in my known list. It works, but it's code that shouldn't be necessary in "perfect world". It will do until, fingers crossed, they address the Github request.

Comment: Yup true that's another way of making it work. See my updated answer for how to avoid having to keep a duplicate list of routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a route for fallback page at the end of the router like so

```
const routes: Route = [
  {path: "OtherPaths",component: OtherPathsComponent},
  {path: "PathNotFound", component: PathNotFoundComponent},
  {path: "**", redirectTo: "PathNotFound"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you, but is that Angular code? I am not using Angular. I don't see how that relates to the way I am using the Ionic router based on my code example above. I have no const routes. Also, I tried using the ** with my component code like this:

<ion-route url="**" component="app-404-page-not-found"></ion-route>

But that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution now - using a dynamic route to catch anything that doesn't match an existing route.

```
  <ion-route url=":any" component="page-404" />
```

If you have protected routes or conditionally rendered routes you can also add that route behind a check like this.

```
  {authLoaded && <ion-route url=":any" component="page-404" />}
```

Found this answer here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18687#issuecomment-781214605

Works for vanilla JS / StencilJS